# BHO, SW_HIDE and Windows 8.1

Tags: winapi, windows-8.1, internet-explorer-11, bho, showwindow

This BHO I have works just fine in Win XP IE 8  and Win 7 IE 11 both 32 bit, but not on Win 8.1 64 bit, no EPM.

It retrieves the HWND of an IE 11 window and calls `ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_HIDE);` on it. The window does not get hidden. Verified with WinSpy that the grabbed window handle is the correct one and the call to the function above returns FALSE with last error = 0.

Help! Thanks

Comment: Do you have a 64 bit version of the BHO? 32 bit DLLs can not be loaded into 64 bit processes.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that the BHO dll is loaded into child iexplore processes running at AppContainer or Low Integirty Levels whereas the HWNDs of Internet Explorer all reside in the parent, main iexplore process running at Medium Integrity Level, thus rendering what I was trying to achieve impossible the way I was attempting.

Comment: Correct. You may extract some code from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21364178/add-browser-action-button-in-internet-explorer-bho/21540353#21540353 (launch a broker process with elevated privilege)